# Firebase "Run firebase use default to activate project APP_NAME"

Tags: firebase

It was successfully when deployed first time, now im trying to deploy again, shows an error:

```
Run firebase use default to activate project MY_APP_NAME
```

**Error:**

> No project active, but a project alias is available.

Comment: Error: No project active, but a project alias is available.

Comment: Which service you are using?

Comment: I'm trying to deploy

Comment: Are you refer [firebase/quickstart-android](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/database) this one?

Comment: No I'm trying to use in web

Answer (score 24, accepted):

At first should `firebase use` to make default alias.

After `firebase use default` to use default.

Then `firebase deploy` yahoo.. you can deploy

Answer (score 32):

When you select a project during firebase init, an alias called default is created for you. To create a new alias, run:

```
firebase use --add
```

Then Firebase CLI will ask you

```
Which project do you want to add? (Use arrow keys)
```

This command allows you to select a Firebase project and give it a named alias. Alias definitions are written to a .firebaserc file inside your project directory.

Answer (score 6):

If you run `firebase use` it should show you an interactive prompt to help you set the active project.

When this is run, it creates a mapping between the directory it was run in and which project / alias you selected, so if you moved the directory the `firebase.json` file is situated in the previous link may have been severed.

Comment: after `firebase use` default is defined, but when `firebase deploy` It gives an error: `Error: No project active, but a project alias is available.`

Comment: Chris, where did you learn about the directory-based mapping?

Comment: I work at Firebase. We expect it to be an implementation detail that hardly ever comes up, though appreciate it's not intuitive why it's broken if it does break because of this.

Answer (score 5):

We are working with CircleCi and this is the way deployment command looks:

```
- run:
   name: Deploy to Firebase
   command: ./firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --force --project production
```

Note the `--project production` flag , "production" is firebase project alias.

Answer (score 4):

Use... firebase use project-ID......
Example:( firebase use rent-1234h)..after this 
type firebase use

hope this will work

Comment: For some reason my problemas just happened on Polymer 3 app, with your advice, it worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

You may need to run commands `firebase login` and `firebase init` again before doing `firebase deploy` it solved problem in my case. 
I also needed to update npm and node.

Answer (score 4):

Please logout from firebase using terminal and try to login in again. This fixed the same issue I was facing.

Use following syntax,
firebase logout
firebase login
firebase use default

Comment: this is what it was for me it even told me I had an "Invalid refresh token" and "did not need to deauthorize" but logged me out and allowed me to log back in

This is after not using firebase through the terminal in well over a year

Answer (score 1):

In my case `firebase logout` and login again by `firebase login` works.

I have the same problem - want to switch project alias to staging after pull my code repo to new machine. I have another project on firebase and logged in the same account as in this project, but error appears:

> Error: No project active, but project aliases are available.

and

> Error: Invalid project selection, please verify project staging exists
>   and you have access.

Verify that in .firebaserc file project alias exist and it tagets to correct project in your account.

Answer (score 1):

In `.firebaserc` get your project name you want to build

Here I got 2 projects name, 1 default for dev env, 1 prod for production env

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "default": {dev_project_name},
    "prod": {production_project_name}
  }
}
```

when you run `firebase deploy` add arg `--project {project_name}`

Deploy to production env

```
firebase deploy --only functions --project prod
```

Deploy to development env

```
firebase deploy --only functions --project default
```